# Specify document encoding of URLConnection's response

Tags: java, urlconnection

```
        URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        connection.connect();

        System.out.println("conncetion successful.");

        String contentType = connection.getContentType();
        System.out.println(contentType);
```

contentType is "text/html; charset=EUC-KR". (may be differ in other locale) and document encdoing is same as one of contentType.

But, When I access same URL("http://google.com") using web brwoser(IE, Firefox, Opera, etc...), it says it's an UTF-8 encoded page. (and document encoding is actually UTF-8.)

I want to get UTF-8 encoded URLConnection, but it seems there is no API.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself.

Google does not check Accept-Charset property in request, but checks User-Agent.
If User-Agent is specifed and well known (Opera, Mozila, etc...), Google send respond in UTF-8.
otherwise the respond will be EUC-KR (may differ in other environment).

So, here is an answer: add this line before connect.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Opera/9.80");
```

you may prefer other agent. (mozila, etc...)